# How to make Rubocop ignore the Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I am trying to get Rubocop running but I am not able to ignore the Gemfile.lock file from the Rubocop configuration.

I am working with a bit of a legacy Rails code base and am trying to get Rubocop running.
In my `.rubocop.yml` file I have:

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - Gemfile.lock
```

However when I run `rubocop` it complains about things in `Gemfile.lock`
If I run `rubocop --force-exclusion Gemfile.lock` then it successfully ignores the Gemfile.lock
What am I doing wrong in the config file?

My version of Ruby is '2.4.10', Rails: '4.2.11.3' and Rubocop '1.12.1'

Comment: You seem to have missed quotation marks. `- 'Gemfile.lock'`

Comment: @titan2gman I tried that and have the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

By default, rubocop does not check gemfile.lock. So there is no need to add it in  Exclude block. Check your .rubocop_todo.yml file for any configration erros. Ensure that you haven't explicitly configured RuboCop to analyze the Gemfile.lock file.

Last solution is to add:

## rubocop:disable all

on top of your gemfile.lock, so rubocop will always ignore this file.

Comment: Thanks.  rubocop:disable all seems to work.  I don't have a .rubocop_todo.yml file.
I'm wondering if it's not just because I have old versions of everything.

Comment: No, I think it never was default behavior to inspect gemfile and lock file. It is probebly due to your configration. If you don't have rubocop_todo.yml, that means you are not using default rubocop configration. You are using your own custom configrations, now you need to check all your configration files, to find out the line that includes the gemfile.lock in inspection.
You are looking for something like:

AllCops:
  Include:
    - '**/*.gemfile'
    - '**/Gemfile'